# VS2010 Web Load Test - How to bind virtual user to a login ID in CSV datasource

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I have a load test with 6 webtests to run and each of them has steps like the following with test mix as “Test mix percentage based on the number of tests started”:

1. Login
2. Do something (can be very long steps)
3. Logout

I set the load run to run with 150 concurrent users (step load pattern) and I have 300 logins in my CSV file.  I read from another thread that I can set virtual user with unique login ID from data source by set data source as “Do Not Move Cursor Automatically” and added a customized pre-request plug in to move data cursor by using the code below:

```
e.WebTest.MoveDataTableCursor(DataSourceName, DataTableName, e.WebTest.Context.WebTestUserId);
```

However, when I start to run the load test, I got index out of range exception from move data table cursor, when I looked at the value of e.WebTest.Context.WebTestUserId, I saw with the test running it just keep growing which then exceeds the total number of record in my csv file.

I then changed the above code to the following to avoid the exception. The exception does not happen anymore but I start to get session lost issues because when the login ids been used up, since it starts from the beginning again which results in two tests running at the same time using the same login id.

```
 e.WebTest.MoveDataTableCursor(DataSourceName, DataTableName, e.WebTest.Context.WebTestUserId % 300);
```

my questions are:

1.How WebTestUserId incremented? Isn’t it supposed to be the virtual user id?

2.How to map each virtual user to a login in in my datasource?

**Update:**
All my webtests are calling the same login test at the beginning and the datasource is associated with the login test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 300 users in the data source and a maximum number of users of 150 there should be no need to set "Do Not Move Cursor Automatically” nor to use `e.WebTest.MoveDataTableCursor()`. Just use the normal data driven approach, setting the access method of the data source to `Sequential` should suffice. With this access method whenever a new test case is to be started by a virtual user the "next" line in the CSV file will be read, after the last record in the file has been read the next record will be the first record in the file. Hence the file may be read several times throughout the test run.

Load test scenarios have a "Percentage of new users" property. This can be set to 100 to indicate that each test starts as a new user.

The phrase "*unique login ID*" has several possible interpretations so would need to know your interpretation to give a precise answer.

**Update**

In a comment you wrote "*All my webtests are calling the same login test at the beginning and the datasource is associated with the login test*". That is the problem. Each web test is getting a copy of the same data from the login test.

One solution is to split the CSV file into multiple files, one file for each web test in the test mix. Set these files as the data sources of the web tests and do not have a data source on the login test. You may need to set the "Inherit web test settings" property on the calls to login. You may also need to set the "Select columns" property of the data source to "Select all columns" to ensure that the login test can read the fields of the data source. But having multiple CSV files leads to the problem of how to read the correct datasource context parameters in the login test.

I have done some testing with a shared login test and found it difficult. I would recommend that each test does it own login, even though that seems contrary to the common goal of factoring out common code. The reason is that the data source values are accessed from the context with strings such as `{{DataSource1.FileName#csv.FieldName}}`. The problem is the `FileName#csv` part needs to be different for each test. It is possible to use a plugin to copy the user name and password from the data source into other context parameters that are used by the login test, then call that plugin in each of the main web tests. Another way may have a plugin in the login test that gets the datasource file name and builds the context parameter names for extracting the datasource fields. The filename might be passed as a context parameter, or it may be possible to access the name at run time from the fields of `e.WebTest...` in the plugin.

**Another approach**

As the tests run with **Percentage of new users** set to 100 you can alter the test mix to specify an initialization test to be run for each virtual user; that could be the login test. The main tests do not explicitly call the login. The initialization test can be set by the load test creation wizard or via the "Edit test mix" command.

Comment: That's what I started with, using 'Sequential' access method, NO custom plugin to move cursor, set tests to run with 'Percentage of new users' as 100% however, I ended up with a lot of session expired issues, when I use a plug in to write the login ids out to a file and then I found that a lot of tests start with the same login id, it seems like they each have a copy of the CSV file and all start from position 0. That was why I then switched to the custimized plugin approach.  All my webtests are calling the same login test at the beginning and the datasource is associated with the login test

Comment: My load test is running locally with a single agent."Unique Login ID" I mean login ids in my csv fine, what I want is during the test execution, there should be a 1:1 mapping between the virtual users and the login ids in my datasource file.

Comment: @Sunny0427 Please modify the question to explain the significant detail added in your comment: "All my webtests are calling the same login test at the beginning and the datasource is associated with the login test".